# Setting Cache-Control header in plesk results in contradiction

Tags: .htaccess, caching, nginx, plesk

I needed to set Cache-Control to be enabled for mobile caching in an app.

Problem was no matter what I put in the .htaccess the response header did not change. It stayed as

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

I tried disabling nginx in plesk and the result was the following:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2628000, public
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

the .htaccess code that I put in there:

```
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2628000, public"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two "Cache-Control" headers in response:

```
Cache-Control:max-age=2628000, public
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
```

It means that you have second definition of "Cache-Control" header , it can be in global apache configs, in VirtualServer of your domain, in another .htaccess.

```
/etc/httpd/ or /etc/apache2/ <-- for global configs
/var/www/vhosts/system/your-domain.tld/conf/ <-- for custom configs
/var/www/vhosts/your-domain.tld/ <-- for another .htaccess files
```

Also back-end application(PHP) and front-end(JavaScript) can add this header.

Comment: the same code worked for my local XAMPP server. It seems that I do not have access to /var/www/... my highest file access only contains the httpd directory. I do have acces to pick which php version and handler to use but I doubt that will matter

Comment: you gave me the idea to think about a second Cache-Control setter. Turns out the cms I was using Processwire set the cache-control to no cache.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the CMS I used (Processwire) set Cache-Control to no cache automatically.

I simply added

```
header_remove("Cache-Control");
```

on pages I want Cache-Control to fully follow my .htaccess